# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to init Cipher using FingerPrint

Tags: java, android, fingerprinting, android-fingerprint-api

I am using fingerprint sdk and it always crash on it.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to init Cipher                                                                                               
at com.example.ammar.fingerbyitself.MainActivity.initCipher(MainActivity.java:160)
at com.example.ammar.fingerbyitself.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:55)
at com.example.ammar.fingerbyitself.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:109)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10814)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Only SecretKey is supported
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.checkAndSetEncodedKey(OpenSSLCipher.java:435)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineInit(OpenSSLCipher.java:260)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:612)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:532)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getSpi(Cipher.java:437)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:815)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:774)
at com.example.ammar.fingerbyitself.MainActivity.initCipher(MainActivity.java:153)
at com.example.ammar.fingerbyitself.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:55) 
at com.example.ammar.fingerbyitself.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:109) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10814) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

When I call CIPHERinit()

```
private boolean initCipher() {
        try {
//            KeyStore mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            mKeyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
            mCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return true;
        } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {

            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
        }
    }
```

Why it crashes is not clear, even the same code is working downloaded from GitHub.

Comment: See the roo cause: Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Only SecretKey is supported

Comment: Is `mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null)` returning `null`? That could be your issue. Is there a key stored in the `AndroidKeyStore` with that alias already? If not, you must create one.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: yes i got solution

Comment: So what is the answer? I can't find any solution for this "Only SecretKey is supported" exception on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when the `SecretKey` I was passing to the `init` function was actually `null`.

That said, I made a library for fingerprint authentication. You may want to give it a shot :

```
FingerprintDialog.initialize(this)
    .title(R.string.title)
    .message(R.string.message)
    .callback(new FingerprintDialogCallback() {
        @Override public void onAuthenticationSucceeded() {}
        @Override public void onAuthenticationCancel() {}
    })
    .show();
```

**[Fingerprint Library](https://github.com/omaflak/FingerprintDialog-Library)**

You can choose to use CryptoObject or not.

Answer (score 1):

In [FingerPrintDialog](https://developer.android.com/samples/FingerprintDialog/index.html) sample there is a `createKey` method that generates the key. After calling `createKey` only you can call `initCipher`

Answer (score 1):

It caused by KEY_NAME is not secret key. You can try another way to init Secret Key by using

```
SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

With keyGenerator is sure in the source code. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

In the function implemented by the FingerPrintDialog sample:

```
private boolean initCipher() {
        try {
//            KeyStore mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            mKeyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
            mCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return true;
        } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {

            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
        }
    }
```

When a Screen Lock reset has occurred  but not a FingerPrint has been enrolled the response is to `throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);` ... So instead of `throwing` the  `RuntimeException`, group all the exceptions in one `catch` and `return false` for every exception in the group:

```
private boolean initCipher(Cipher cipher, String keyName) {
        try {
            mKeyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(keyName, null);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return true;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

or maybe,

```
private int initCipher(Cipher cipher, String keyName) {
        try {
            mKeyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(keyName, null);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return 1;
        } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
            return 0;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean initCipher(Cipher cipher, String keyName) {
        try {
            mKeyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(keyName, null);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return true;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

"return false;" This work fine for me